# PHP7 - class static variable doesn't support variable function

Tags: php, static-methods, static-members, static-variables

In PHP7.4.3, I'm trying to use class static variable to refer to different class static member functions as below:

```
1  class ColorT {
2    static $color = "yellow";
3    static function yellow() {
4        echo "yellow"."<br>";
5    }
6    static function green() {
7        echo "green"."<br>";
8    }
9  }

10 ColorT::$color();  //ColorT::yellow() function is expected to be called

11 $global_color = "yellow";
12 ColorT::$global_color();  //ColorT::yellow() function is expected to be called
```

Both line 10 and line 12, I expect `ColorT::yellow()` to be invoked.
Line 12 works as expected.
But in line 10, it print error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string

Doesn't php support class static variable referring to class static member functions?
If it's supported, then how to fix the error mentioned in line 10?

Comment: Would `ColorT::{ColorT::$color}();` help? I'm not sure if your priority is to only use the classname once, or just to be able to call the method dynamically in one line. That should work as far back as PHP 5.4. See https://3v4l.org/kbBVq

Comment: @iainn I just want to call the method dynamically in one line and your solution works! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In line 10, `ColorT::$color` is "yellow". So `ColorT::$color()` would call `yellow()`, not `ColorT::yellow()`.

You could use the [callbable](https://www.php.net/callable) `['ColorT', ColorT::$color]` for this, to call `ColorT::yellow()`, dynamically.

Example :

```
class ColorT {
  static $color = "yellow";
  static function yellow() {
      echo "yellow"."<br>";
  }
  static function green() {
      echo "green"."<br>";
  }
}

$method = ['ColorT', ColorT::$color];
$method();
```

Output :

```
yellow<br>
```

---

Another way is to create a method in ColorT :

```
static public function callFunc() 
{
    [__class__, self::$color]();
}
```

and use

```
ColorT::callFunc(); // "yellow<br>"
```

You can also check using [`is_callable()`](https://www.php.net/is_callable)